# An example of a function of two variables that is continuous for every variable but not continuous on both simultaneously.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, continuity

The function $f$ defined on the unit square $0 \leq s \leq 1$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$ is given below:

$$\begin{equation*}
f(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } s = t =0,\\
\frac{s+t}{\sqrt{s^2 + t^2}}. & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

And the book said that this is a function of two variables that is continuous at every point of its domain of definition with respect to each variable but is not continuous in both variables simultaneously.

**My question is:**

Why the function is not continuous in $s$ and $t$ simultaneously?

I took the path $s =2t$ and I got the limit $3/\sqrt{5}$ at $(s,t) \rightarrow (0,0),$ but $f(0,0) =1$. Is this is the reason that the function is not continuous at $s$ & $t$ simultaneously?

Comment: yes,,,,,,,,,,,,